# dump js variable on a non browser JS environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to debug why stylelint app cannot find my config file in my PhpStorm IDE.
Stylelint, a JS based app (nodeJS?) is executed and the process finish with that error:

```
stylelint._fullExplorer.load.then.then.config (K:\dev\npm packages\node_modules\stylelint\lib\getConfigForFile.js:47:15)
```

how can i somehow visualise the value of that searchPath variable at runtime?

```
  if (!config) {
        const ending = searchPath ? ` for ${searchPath}` : "";
        throw configurationError(`No configuration provided${ending}`);
```

Is there an easy way to do something similar than a console log(searchPath), save that value in a file or something?

Comment: Have you *tried* `console.log`? NodeJS has it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like stylelint is indeed a Node app. Node has `console.log`, so unless standard output is being hidden, that would indeed work.

Comment: where can i see the output of a console.log if stylelint is not executed from a browser?

Comment: @Matoeil: NodeJS output is sent to the terminal. So if you run it from a terminal window, you should see the output there. (Again, provided it's not redirected.)